# How to set defaults for java.util.Properties at any time?

Tags: java, inheritance, properties, default

Passing `defaults` as an argument when constructing a `java.util.Properties` seems to be a easy way to create hierarchy of properties where children logically inherit values defined in (grand)parents, and every value can be overrided if it is required.

At the same time the only way to pass these `defaults` into a properties object is to use the constructor. What if I don't control creation of the object? There is no setter that would allow me to do this at any time, like `setDefaults(Properties defaults)`.

Looking through the source code of `java.util.Properties` I have found nothing that disallows me to extend the class and add the setter that I need.

My questions are following:

1. What do you think of the solution?
2. Why the API developers haven't done this themselves?

Comment: Do you any issues in setting defaults through constructor? If Yes, you can use - getProperty(String key, String defaultValue)

Comment: Do you any issues in setting defaults through constructor? If Yes, you can use - getProperty(String key, String defaultValue) for individual property while retrieving the value

Comment: Yes I do. Objects of Properties are issued by a specific caching factory method, I can't pass defaults there so want to set the defaults externally. After that no client is aware about the default values - it's not their responsibility. They just read values. Indeed I know about getProperty(String key, String defaultValue). It simply doesn't suit here! Did you read about my idea of inheritance at all?

Comment: Looks like I did not understand problem completely and I am not seeing issues.  If you cannot set the defaults in the construction, construct Properties whenever data is ready and enable callers to use the properties only after setting the default properties.

Comment: I'm trying to organize a cache for Properties objects to prevent them loading from disk each time I need them. An object can be a parent for several other objects. If I need a parental object and it is already loaded I'd rather get it from the cache rather than loading. Caching facility know nothing about relations between objects. I could pass parent object as a factory method parameter, but I don't like to do it this way. But even if I overcome the problem I will be curious about the answer for the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `java.util.Properties` [will not be changed ever](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4366529), so it is safe to extend the class and bring my functionality there. I also consider switching to a different API in the future to implement the mechanism.